# Update rows from one table to another table based on Id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Both tables have a client_id column. Need to insert data from #LocalDashboardtable into T004_Dashboard when the client_id column are equal. i have tried this but it does't help  shows an error "Incorrect syntax near ','. "

```
    update T004_Dashboard  set T004_Dashboard.[GrossCharge],T004_Dashboard.[NetCharge] 
= (select #LocalDashboardtable.[GrossCharge] , #LocalDashboardtable.[NetCharge] 
from #LocalDashboardtable   where 
#LocalDashboardtable.client_id =T004_Dashboard.client_id and 
#LocalDashboardtable.[month] =T004_Dashboard.[month] 
and #LocalDashboardtable.[year] =T004_Dashboard.[year]  )
```

pls help me

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax but the question is tagged MySQL.  Which database are you really using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

This is your query (which looks a lot like SQL Server):

```
update T004_Dashboard
    set T004_Dashboard.[GrossCharge],
        T004_Dashboard.[NetCharge] = (select #LocalDashboardtable.[GrossCharge], #LocalDashboardtable.[NetCharge] 
                                      from #LocalDashboardtable
                                      where #LocalDashboardtable.client_id = T004_Dashboard.client_id and 
                                            #LocalDashboardtable.[month] = T004_Dashboard.[month] and
                                            #LocalDashboardtable.[year] = T004_Dashboard.[year]
                                     );
```

You cannot set a pair of columns to a pair of columns in a subquery.  Instead, use a `join`:

```
update T004_Dashboard
    set GrossCharge = ld.GrossCharge,
        NetCharge = ld.NetCharge
    from T004_Dashboard d join
         #LocalDashboardtable ld
         on ld.[month] = d.[month] and ld.[year] = d.[year] and
            ld.client_id = d.client_id;
```

Also, SQL Server does not allow qualified column names in `update/set` statements